# How to set a select list is for a model as dropdownlistfor in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a select list which I bind it in ajax post. I want to use it instead of `DropDownListFor(model=>model...)`

Here is my codes :

```
   function GetDateReadingMeter(meterId) {
        // GetMeterReadingDates
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetMeterReadingDates", "ApartmentAccrual")',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "meterId": meterId }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {

                var markup = "<option value='0'>Sayaç Okuma Tarihi Seçiniz</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].d + ">" + data[x].d + "</option>";

                }
                $("#ddlReadingDate").html(markup).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

In html...

```
 <select class="select1" id="ddlReadingDate" name="ddlReadingDate" style="width: 200px"></select> 
// I want to use this select instead of ==>
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MeterAccrualViewModel.SayacTahakkuk.ReadingDate, "", new { type = "text", @class = "select1" })
```

Comment: just don't use the `DropDownListFor` helper method. Make sure you have the proper name attribute value for your hand coded SELECT element.

Comment: Why in the world would you not want to use the `DropDownListFor()` ? You an make it `name="MeterAccrualViewModel.SayacTahakkuk.ReadingDate"` but that will never give you correct 2-way model binding (and `new { type = "text" }` is not a valid attribute for a `<select>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlReadingDate", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select ",new { @style="width:200px;"})
```

And bind it on ajax success:

```
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {

            $('#ddlReadingDate').append('<option value="' + value.Id+ '">' + value.Date+'</option>');

        });
```

Need to make some changes accordingly your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. And how can I pass the selected value to controller as model's ReadingDate ?

Comment: Here your are not doing data binding to the model, so you can get it in like`var value1 = Request["ddlReadingDate"];`